# Find duplicate child nodes in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, child-nodes

I have a column in oracle database that stores XML data.

For some reason, a query of mine was not checking for existing nodes while inserting it and hence has caused duplicates nodes in few rows.

I am not able to find an effective way to find those duplicates.

My XML looks like:

```
<myroot>
  <mydata>

    <myusers>
      <username>amy</username>
      <userrole/>
      <userrole>junior artist</userrole>
    </myusers>

    <myusers>
      <username>rosy</username>
      <userrole/>
      <userrole>junior artist</userrole>
    </myusers>

    <myusers>
      <username>timmy</username>
      <userrole>junior artist</userrole>
    </myusers>

  </mydata>
</myroot>
```

As shown in the above XML example,  empty node is sitting idle in few tags of few rows but is there a way I can just find which rows contain duplicates ?

In past I've used below query to just extract this data but don't know how to extract data of two:

```
SELECT MYID, EXTRACT(MYDATA, 'myroot/mydata/myusers/userole/text()') 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE
EXISTNODE(MYDATA, 'myroot/mydata/myusers/userole') = 1
```

Just for background, my other data extract query is not sending below error is the reason why now the need to fix above data:

```
ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence
```

Comment: Yes, Corrected the typo. userrole is duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to find out the Count of "myusers" tags and "userrole". Where ever the count was mismatch were the rows which needed attention. I had 2000 rows and two of them had the duplicate so this solution worked fine for me. But if it was a different set of data, I think @Matthew McPeak's solution would work great.

I am sure there may be better and effective ways of doing this but below is the one-time query that worked fine for me.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
    select count(*) MYCON, MYID
        from MYTABLE  sa
        cross join xmltable('myroot/mydata/myusers'
            passing sa.MYDATA columns myusers varchar2(1) path '@dummy'
    ) 
    GROUP BY MYID ) BB
JOIN
    (
    select count(*) YOURCON, MYID
        from MYTABLE sa
        cross join xmltable('myroot/mydata/myusers/userrole'
            passing sa.MYDATA columns myusers varchar2(1) path '@dummy'
    ) 
    GROUP BY MYID ) AA
ON  AA.MYID = BB.MYID
WHERE MYCON <> YOURCON
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using 'XMLTABLE' in lieu of the other, now deprecated 'EXTRACT' functions.

If you have your XML in a table, which I'll call "tbl" in my example below, you can do it like this:

```
with tbl as
(
    select
        XMLType(
        '<myroot>
          <mydata>

            <myusers>
              <username>amy</username>
              <userrole/>
              <userrole>junior artist</userrole>
            </myusers>

            <myusers>
              <username>rosy</username>
              <userrole/>
              <userrole>junior artist</userrole>
            </myusers>

            <myusers>
              <username>timmy</username>
              <userrole>junior artist</userrole>
            </myusers>

          </mydata>
        </myroot>'
        ) xmldata
    from
        dual
)
select username, userrole
from (
    select username, userrole, count(*) over ( partition by username) rolecnt
    from   tbl,
           xmltable('/myroot/mydata/myusers/userrole' 
                          PASSING tbl.xmldata 
                          COLUMNS username VARCHAR2(80) PATH './../username', 
                                  userrole VARCHAR2(80) PATH '.')
    )
where rolecnt > 1
```

> ```
> +----------+---------------+
> | USERNAME |   USERROLE    |
> +----------+---------------+
> | amy      |               |
> | amy      | junior artist |
> | rosy     |               |
> | rosy     | junior artist |
> +----------+---------------+
> ```

N.B. I assumed "userole" in your input data was a typo and that you meanst "userrole".

Comment: I liked your solution and it worked great on the example but when I ran on my database values, the username never showed any value. It was always blank. So I found another way of doing which worked for my set of data.